# if statement in php not behaving as I expect

Tags: php, if-statement

I have searched the forum but still cannot find the answer to this question. I want to produce different results depending on what is sent to my page. The code is as follows:

```
$picture=$_GET['pic'];
echo "Picture ref= " . $picture . "<br>";
if ($picture="one"){
    echo "now on 1<br>";
    $image="tears-14.jpg";
    $picture="Tears";
    $orient="port";
}
elseif ($picture="two"){
    echo "now on 2<br>";
    $image="music-12.jpg";
    $picture="The Music Has Landed";
    $orient="land";
}
echo "Picture ref after processing: " . $picture . "<br>";
```

If I use http://www.???.com/art.php?pic=two as the url I get the following incorrect response:
Picture ref= two
now on 1
Picture ref after processing: Tears.

Which means the code is not behaving the way I want it to, as the result I should get is:
Picture ref= two
now on 2
Picture ref after processing: The Music has Landed

I am new and would appreciate it if somebody could point out what is probably a simple error.

Many thanks and apologies if you think I am wasting your time.

Tog Porter

Comment: `= NOt equal to ==` o_O

Answer (score 2):

Use the `==` operator to check if values are equal:

```
 $picture = $_GET['pic'];
    echo "Picture ref= " . $picture . "<br>";
    if ($picture == "one"){
        echo "now on 1<br>";
        $image="tears-14.jpg";
        $picture="Tears";
        $orient="port";
    }
    elseif ($picture == "two"){
        echo "now on 2<br>";
        $image="music-12.jpg";
        $picture="The Music Has Landed";
        $orient="land";
    }
    echo "Picture ref after processing: " . $picture . "<br>";
```

Comment: How stupid of me. Thank you so much @Olly Tenerife for your help and quick response:-)

Answer (score 0):

Because you use assignment operator instead of comparison operator

change `=` to `==`

That is why it's better to use

```
if ("one" == $picture) {
```

instead of

```
if($picture = $one) {
```